# Access Scsi devices with lun more than 255

Tags: scsi

I am a noob using Ubuntu server 12.04.5 LTS. There is a need for me to access a SCSI device with logical unit number(LUN) more than 255.According to my knowledge we can't see SCSI devices with lun more than 255. I heard, there is  flat space addressing mode for lun which supports lun more than 255. Can I access the volumes(SCSI device) using flat space addressing in Ubuntu? If it is, how?

Please reply if you need further info and excuse me if I made any mistakes in my question.

Comment: Which HBA are you using?  There are various methods to setting the "max luns", see http://pinoyunix.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-check-for-maximum-supported-luns-in.html for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply gubblebozer.  Sorry I was not very clear. This is my configuration setup. I have an windows xp service pack 3 host which is running VMWARE workstation 6.5 with VM Ubuntu server 12.04.5 LTS . My requirement is to connect to a remote storage array through iscsi using  iscsiadm utility from ubuntu  VM(As a initiator)and access the volumes present on the remote array whose lun is  256. The windows xp host has Intel(R) 82562V-2 10/100 NIC and the storage array has a controller with  QLogic 4032 PCIX iSCSI Adapter. Is it possible with these requirements?

Comment: It's likely that you won't be able to see more than 256 LUNs at one time, but Linux will support LUNs with numbers greater than 256, after a fashion anyway.  There seems to be some disagreement about which part of the kernel is supposed to translate the flat space addressing method (at least on my older 2.6.32 kernel.)  For LUNs in the 300's I end up with untranslated LUNs numbered up around 16700.  But, f you use `sg_luns -d <dev>`, it'll reveal the correctly translated one.